# Infinite Series: While loop ends in infinity

Tags: c#, math, while-loop, series, infinite

I want to compute a series, but i don't get my do..while loop correct.
The user makes in input x, which then is summed up as following:
sum = sum + x / 2 ^ n, where n is the running variable.

This has to be looped, until the sum <= 0.00001.

Then the program will notify the user about the value of the sum and how big the running variable is.

My code so far:

```
public static int n = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

double x, sum = 0, e = 0.00001;

Console.Write("input x: ");
x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

do
{
  sum = sum + x / Math.Pow(2,n);
  n++;
} while (sum >= e);

Console.WriteLine ("Sum = " + sum + ", " + n + " count");

}
```

But my code results in an infinite loop. Do you have any ideas, how i could achieve it?

Comment: because sum is always coming greater than e.

Comment: because sum always bigger than e

Comment: `sum` is increasing, how will it ever get smaller than `e`? Perhaps you want to loop until x/2^n gets less than `e`?

Comment: You can use that old maths formula also sum = a / (1- r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looping until the *sum* is very small; you should loop until the *increment* is very small:

```
var delta = e;
do
{
  delta = x / Math.Pow(2,n);
  sum = sum + delta;
  n++;
} while (delta >= e);
```

Comment: computing x / 2 ^ n in a own variable worked well! thank you very much for the help